# Rails NameError uninitialized constant in has_many :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

I have the following models defined:

house_firm.rb

```
class HouseFirm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :house_firm_group_links
  has_many :house_firm_groups, through: :house_firm_group_links
end
```

house_firm_group.rb

```
class HouseFirmGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :house_firm_group_links
  has_many :house_firms, through: :house_firm_group_links
end
```

house_form_group_link.rb

```
class HouseFirmGroupLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house_firm
  belongs_to :house_firm_group
end
```

However, when I do:

```
@house_firm = HouseFirm.new
@house_firm.house_firm_groups
```

I receive:

```
NameError at /house_firms/new

uninitialized constant HouseFirm::HouseFirmGroupLink
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in the name of the file implementing `HouseFirmGroupLink` class, it should be named `house_firm_group_link.rb`.

Comment: Oh...stared 15 minutes on the three files looking for a typo but couldn't find one...Thanks a million!